# Dynamic Content missing in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am following a tutorial where they are getting an option to add dynamic content in outlook **`Send an email (V2)`**.

However, I am not getting this option in my outlook **`Send an email (V2)`**.

Any help is much appreciated.

Link to tutorial: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Hcvn9TQ5fM&ab_channel=WafaStudies**

at Time: **(12:35)**

### Their Screenshot:

[image]

### My Screenshot:

:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using a [Standard logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-azure-portal#create-a-standard-logic-app-resource). In the above tutorial, the author used a [Consumption logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-example-consumption-workflow#create-a-consumption-logic-app-resource) and thats why using dynamic content was different from yours.

To use dynamic content or previous step output in a standard logic app, you need to use like below.

[image]

Click on that icon to add data from previous step.

[image]

Now, you can see the parameters of previous step. To use dynamic expressions, click on `fx` icon below that.

If you want to use dynamic content as same as the above tutorial, then use a consumption logic app.

**My sample result after calling it from ADF web activity:**

[image]